# Help me understand why $\frac{dt}{dx} = 2x \iff dt = 2x \cdot dx$ is invalid

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is $\displaystyle\frac{dt}{dx} = 2x \iff dt = 2x \cdot dx$ not valid? My understanding is that $\displaystyle\frac{dt}{dx} = 2x \implies dt = 2x \cdot dx$ is however valid.

Why can we treat $\displaystyle\frac{dt}{dx}$ as a fraction? And why the limitations?

Comment: $t=x^2 \implies dt=2x\ dx$.

Comment: peterwhy: thanks! That was a stupid mistake of me. Fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle\frac{dt}{dx}$ is a limit. Both $dt$ and $dx$ symbolize formulas $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ that approaches zero. Your equivalent then only means $0=0$.

Comment: So simple, awesome! :) Thanks!